# Coldfusion 11 Apache Commons 3.0.1 FTPClient RetrieveFileStream() returns null

Tags: java, ftp-client

I'm creating a class to use in Coldfusion to replace the cfftp tag so I can do FTP over SSL.  I have a custom tag that interacts with the class, using either FTPClient or FTPSClient.  Connecting, logging in, putting a file, changing directories, listing files all work, but I cannot get a file for the life of me.  I have tried both the retrieveFile() and retrieveFileStream methods and neither works.  Below is my getFile method implemented with retrieveFileStream() and the inputstream is always null, no matter what.  The file is there and the permissions are good.  I just have no idea at this point.  I can connect and get the file through WSFTP without a problem, so I think it's something in my implementation. Any help is appreciated!

```
public void getFile(String localFileName, String remoteFileName, String transferMode) {
    try {
        int transferFileType = 0;

        existsFile(remoteFileName);

        if (getReturnValue() != "YES" || replyCode == 550) {
            throw new IOException("File " + remoteFileName + " does not exist");
        }
        else {
            Boolean transferComplete = false;
            File downloadFile = new File(localFileName);
            OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
            InputStream input;
            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            if (!downloadFile.canWrite()) {
                setSucceeded(false);
                output.close();
                throw new IOException("Cannot write to file " + localFileName);
            }
            if (!isConnected()) {
                setSucceeded(false);
                output.close();
                throw new IOException("Connection closed by server.");
            }

            if (getSecure()) {

                if (transferMode.toUpperCase() == "BINARY") {
                    ftps.setFileType(ftps.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                }
                else {
                    ftps.setFileType(ftps.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
                }

                ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                ftps.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);

                try {

                    input = ftps.retrieveFileStream(remoteFileName);
                    setReplyCode(true);
                    if (input == null || replyCode == 550) {
                        setSucceeded(false);
                        output.close();
                        throw new IOException("Cannot read file " + remoteFileName);
                    }
                    else {
                        while ((bytesRead = input.read(bytesArray)) != -1) {
                            output.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
                            output.flush();
                        }

                        input.close();
                        output.close();
                        transferComplete = ftps.completePendingCommand();
                        setReplyCode(true);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    processError(e);
                }
            }
            else {

                if (transferMode.toUpperCase() == "BINARY") {
                    ftp.setFileType(ftps.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                }
                else {
                    ftp.setFileType(ftps.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
                }

                ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                ftp.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);

                try {

                    input = ftp.retrieveFileStream(remoteFileName);
                    setReplyCode(true);
                    if (input == null || replyCode == 550) {
                        setSucceeded(false);
                        output.close();
                        throw new IOException("Cannot read file " + remoteFileName);
                    }
                    else {
                        while ((bytesRead = input.read(bytesArray)) != -1) {
                            output.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
                            output.flush();
                        }

                        input.close();
                        output.close();
                        transferComplete = ftp.completePendingCommand();
                        setReplyCode(true);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    processError(e);
                }
            }
            //setReturnValue("Bytes Read: " + Integer.toString(bytesRead));
            setSucceeded(transferComplete);
            setReplyCode(true);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        processError(e);
    }
}
```

Here's my open connection method:

```
public void open (String server_in, int port_in, int timeout_in, String username_in, String password_in, Boolean implicit_in, Boolean secure_in) {
    try {
        FTPClientConfig conf = new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX);

        if (secure_in) {
            setSecure(true);
            ftps = new FTPSClient("SSL", implicit_in);  // Create the client object
            ftps.configure(conf);  // Set the system type
            String[] protocolVersions = {"SSLv3"};
            ftps.setEnabledProtocols(protocolVersions);  //  Enable SSLv3 protocol
            ftps.setAutodetectUTF8(true);  //  Enable auto detect
            ftps.connect(server_in, port_in);  //  Connect
            setReplyCode(true);  //  Get server response

            ftps.setConnectTimeout(timeout_in);

            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode))
            {
                ftps.disconnect();
                throw new Exception("FTP server refused connection.");
            }

            ftps.login(username_in, password_in);
            setReplyCode(true);  //  Get server response

            ftps.execPBSZ(0);  //  Set protection buffer to 0
            ftps.execPROT("P");  //  Private protocol
            ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        }
        else {
            setSecure(false);
            ftp = new FTPClient();  // Create the client object
            ftp.configure(conf);  // Set the system type
            ftp.connect(server_in, port_in);
            setReplyCode(true);  //  Get server response
            ftp.setAutodetectUTF8(true);  //  Enable auto detect
            ftp.setConnectTimeout(timeout_in);

            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode))
            {
                ftp.disconnect();
                throw new Exception("FTP server refused connection.");
            }

            ftp.login(username_in, password_in);
            setReplyCode(true);  //  Get server response
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        }

        setSucceeded(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        processError(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know there's a lot going on here with the interaction with CF11, but the crux of the matter is the Java FTP call.  I think I'm missing something simple, but I can't see it.  Let me know if you need more info or if this code works on your machine, too!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.  If you look at my getFile() method above you'll see that I first check to make sure the file exists with existsFile(remoteFileName).  Well, the method I was using to see if a file exists was to to open an InputStream with retrieveFileStream() to it within a try block and throw an error if it failed.  I never called completePendingCommand() after the retrieveFileStream() in existsFile(), so trying to open another stream to the file always failed.  Phew!